# XMLType with 238 characters fails

Tags: oracle, odp.net, xmltype

With Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 4.121.2.0 product version "4.121.2.20141216 ODAC RELEASE 3" and product version "4.121.2.20150926 ODAC RELEASE 4", the use of OracleXmlType with a value of 238 characters fails. If i use 239 or 237 characters it's work fine. At the beginning, i thinked that because i have a special character like ( or / but i replaced all characters by 'a' and i have the same issue and the error message is very strange (sorry for the french):

> ORA-31011: Echec d'analyse XML ORA-19202: Une erreur s'est produite
>   lors du traitement la fonction XML ( LPX-00231: invalid character 47
>   ('/') found in a Name or Nmtoken)

See below my unit test, used to reproduce the issue:

```
using(Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection connection = new Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(myConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using(Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try 
        {
            Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand command = new Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand();
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MYTABLE(XML_VALUE) VALUES (:XML_VALUE)";
            command.Connection = connection;
            Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types.OracleXmlType xmlValue = new Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types.OracleXmlType(connection, "<root>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</root>");
            using(Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter parameter = new Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter("XML_VALUE", Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.XmlType, xmlValue, ParameterDirection.Input))
            {
                command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        } finally {
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

And the script of table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE(XML_VALUE XMLTYPE NOT NULL)
```

Comment: I just tried with ODP.Net 4.112.3.0 and it works fine. I suspect it may be related to code page mismatch between server and client.

Comment: Same thing happens on Oracle.ManagedDataAccess version 4.121.2.0 for 258 characters.